Os.setEnv / System.setProperty not working on emulator
My app is carrying the native NDK library (*.so), which needs for work environment variables set up before execute it's methods- the app layer does that at the Application start before running the native part through JNI further.
I've implemented Os.setEnv and that does the job on literally every physical device app is running, probably dozens of diff units starting API27 tried till now by last over dozen of months. Also, I've heard that app works well on emulator on ARM Mac, but I've just configured ARM-handling emulator (as my *.so lib is arm64 only) on my Windows, app runs, setEnvs, then run native code, which... reports lack of envs... why?
I also tried System.setProperty, without luck

workaround - pico-native-lib for setting envs on native side:
#include <jni.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_my_package_name_Sandbox_setenv(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jstring key, jstring value) {
    const char *nativeKey = env->GetStringUTFChars(key, 0);
    const char *nativeValue = env->GetStringUTFChars(value, 0);

    if (nativeKey != nullptr && nativeValue != nullptr) {
        setenv(nativeKey, nativeValue, 1);
    }

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(key, nativeKey);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(value, nativeValue);
    return 0;
}

framework side (Java):
package my.package.name;

public class Sandbox {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Sandbox");
    }

    public static native int setenv(String key, String value);
}

calling now both Os.setEnv and Sandbox.setenv, works everywhere
not marking as answer, as very curious why I did that...
